# Flash message in redirect not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my controller:

```
redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "The email is already registered"
```

In my view I have

```
<%= flash[:notice] if flash[:notice] %>
```

But the flash message does not appear.

However if I do the following in the controller

```
flash[:notice] = "There is already an acount for this email. Please Login to create your board."
redirect_to signin_path
```

It does work.
What is the reason the first one does not work?

Comment: Are `signup_path` and `signin_path` different?

Comment: I corrected the error. It was supposed to read signin_path

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do some tail'ing on your logs and see if you're being redirected to multiple actions before you render. If you are, it's likely that flash isn't being kept long enough to make it to the view where it is finally rendered.

A well-placed `flash.keep(:notice)` should do the trick.

**Much later edit:** Also, in retrospect, if you're redirecting that many times, I highly suggest you do some refactoring and eliminate any unnecessary jumps by consolidating your redirect logic at a higher level, so that your redirects are predetermined and only happen once, twice max.

Comment: Had no idea about this. Brilliant find mate.

Comment: Check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for the rails guides notes on this. the `flash.keep` should go to the intermediate controller. That is, if you have `apples redirect_to tree which redirects_to ground` it should go inside the `tree`controller action where the second redirect happens

Comment: Also note, using just `flash.keep` without any params will keep the *entire* flash.

Answer (score 6):

simple, but effective:

modify ApplicationController < ActionController::Base as follows:

```
alias :std_redirect_to :redirect_to
def redirect_to(*args)
   flash.keep
   std_redirect_to *args
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to write these line in views/layouts/application.html.erb file

```
<%= notice %>
<%= alert %>
```

and write

`layout 'application'` in controllers

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Any idea why the first line I wrote does not work?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, since it works, so here's a +1

Comment: This got me past my own issue, I needed a handle the notice via my custom stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

IN your controller use:

```
redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "There is already an acount for this email. Please Login to create your board."
```

In your application layout use:

```
<%= notice %>
```