# Devise not showing success messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise is behaving strangely. It shows the red or the error messages, but it does not show the green or success messages.

This happened after I made changes to the routing and controller to redirect to sign-in page or home page according to whether the user is signed-in or not.

So the routes.rb now has:

```
devise_for :users

root :to => "questions#redirect_on_visit" 

match 'home', :to => "questions#index"
```

and the controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:redirect_on_visit]

def redirect_on_visit
  if user_signed_in?       
    redirect_to home_path      
  else    
    redirect_to new_user_session_path      
  end
end
```

Also changed application controller to redirect to appropriate pages after sign-in/sign-out:

```
 protected

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)    
   stored_location_for(:user) || root_path      
 end

 private

 def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
   stored_location_for(:user) || root_path    
 end
```

Comment: What do you see on your flash object when you login or logout I guess devise write those info as `flash[:notice]` and not as `flash[:success]`

Comment: Yes! It is of course `flash[:notice]`. By success messages I mean the messages that say you have signed in or signed out successfully. Devise marks them with green background.

Comment: I'm sure about the background color but if your concern is flash message inspect `devise.yml` (in `config/locales` directory) file will give you more insight on it

Comment: No my concern is not the content of flash messages, but the fact that they don't show up after I made the changes I mentioned in the question above.

Comment: you mean you can see the message in the flash object but can see them on screen

Comment: Exactly! Those messages appear fine if I revert the changes I have made. But I did figure out one part of the problem. The `redirect_on_visit` is actually redirecting again when Devise is done redirecting, hence the flash message is lost. So I added a `flash[:notice]` before `redirect_to home_path` and that solves the sign-in success message. However, still looking for how to do the same for sign-out because with sign-out there is no redirecting again.

Comment: You are right Know I when a looked at your code I guess you code redirect_on_visit is the reason why your flash message doesnot appear on the intendend page as flash object leave for a single request and your method is actually doing a second redirect on the which is causing the flash message to disapper . perhap it would be better you remove the the redirect_to_vist and write those routing logic in `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_sign_out_path_for` instead of root_path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was being extremely numb. The fact that I have `root :to => "questions#redirect_on_visit"`, will redirect each time a user visits, signs in or signs out. Redirect was clearly washing away the flash messages.

Finally I found the solution I was looking for. It is to preserve the flash messages `flash.keep(:notice)` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426526/flash-message-in-redirect-not-working-rail3).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the multiple redirection from **login  => root => home** 
as flash object has a life leave only for a single request

I guess It would be better of writing `redirect_on_visit` routing in `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_sign_out_path_for`

something like this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)    
   stored_location_for(:user) ||  home_path    
 end

 private

 def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
   stored_location_for(:user) || new_user_session_path   
 end
```

Comment: No you got it wrong. The `redirect_on_visit` works before a user has signed in, while these two methods work AFTER a user has signed-in or signed-out.

Comment: @Humming Perhaps you did not get what i meant you problem is when devise authenticate a user it redirect the user to `root_path` in your case it is `questions#redirect_on_visit` now when the redirection happen to root_path till then flash message exist but since your check for logged in user using `user_signed_in?` in `redirect_on_visit` and then redirecting it back to `home` page your flash message get lost do yourself a favour and add a `debugger` in the `if statement` of `redirect_on_visit` and examine the `flash content` you will see the devise message there now since you are redirecting

Comment: @Humming it to the home_path your flash message is lost in that transition bcoz as i said before as flash message only prevail for a single request