# redirecting a POST request in ruby-on-rails causes flash hash to be wiped out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, redirect

When trying to redirect a POST request I'm finding that rails' flash hash is getting wiped out.

The redirect works fine when the initial request is a GET.

in config/routes.rb

```
post 'test/hello' 
#get 'test/hello' #uncomment this line and comment out the post and the flash is preserved
get 'test/goodbye'
```

in app/controllers/test_controller.rb

```
def hello
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
            redirect_to movies_goodbye_url, :notice => "I disappear on post requests"
        end
    end
end

def goodbye
end
```

in app/views/test/goodbye.html.haml

```
%h1 Test#goodbye
%p#alert= alert
%p#notice= notice
```

I want this action to handle posts from a form submission which redirects in error cases to one of my existing views. I'm pretty new to rails so if there's a better way to handle this use-case, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a [`flash.keep`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash/FlashHash.html#M000311) in there:

```
flash.keep(:notice)
redirect_to movies_goodbye_url, :notice => "I disappear on post requests"
```

See also: [Flash message in redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426526/flash-message-in-redirect-not-working-rail3)

Comment: +1 Great catch! But WHY does Rails work this way??? Should this be submitted as a bug to their bug tracker?