# Flash[:notice] does not appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this conditional in my application.html file:

```
<% if flash[:notice]%>
<div class="nav_notice">
<%=  flash[:notice] %>
</div>
```

And for example, controller method:

```
def create_guest
  @user=User.new
  @user.guest=true
  if @user.save(:validate=>false)
    cookies[:auth_token] = {:value => @user.auth_token, :expires => Time.now+ 30.days}

    redirect_to session_checker, :notice=>'true'
  end
  end
```

No notice. Why?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426526/flash-message-in-redirect-not-working-rail3

Comment: Try some debugging. Examine the contents of your `flash` array.

Comment: @meagar flash[:notice] is nil, and I can't get why

Comment: just tried on a dummy application, it works just fine. By the way you forgot to close the `if` in your view `<% end %>`. Which version of Rails ?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois, yes, that may be the key

Comment: no, just forgot it while copypasting

Comment: You wouldn't have your html if that was the case

Comment: you probably have a redirection, have you tried using `flash.keep` ?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo, yes, I found out, that root_url is conditional, so actually two redirects there, where should I place flash.keep

Comment: If you want, you can answer your own question (or I could do it), so it wont stay unanswered. Glad I could help

Comment: Answer, I will approve, also mention, that `redirect_to profile_url, :notice => flash[:notice]` also worked for me with double redirect and flashed initial message

Comment: @JoeHalfFace that's what the post I linked was about...

Comment: Well, let's be fair then, @Pierre-LouisGottfrois, you answer :), and we all win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a redirection to multiple actions. Try this

```
flash.keep(:notice)
```

Also see here:

[Flash message in redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426526/flash-message-in-redirect-not-working-rail3)