# Rails flash missing from session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did an upgrade from Rails 3.2 to 4.0 and now none of my flash messages work after a redirect.

I checked to make sure it's not a problem with the way I'm *displaying* the flash messages. Flash messages that don't involve a redirect work fine.

### Flash missing from session

I dug into it and noticed something interesting. If I put a [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) on the controller action I redirect to, I can see that `session["flash"]` is `nil`. I don't believe `session["flash"]` should be `nil` at that point.

If I enter `session.keys` into the console, it shows me this:

```
["session_id", "kmq", "warden.user.user.key", "_csrf_token", "foo"]
# "foo" is something I added myself as a test
```

Shouldn't there be a session key called `"flash"`?

### Flash missing from env

I look at the [FlashHash source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dd0dc3e7217f8af7877c5831b3d8816d156f21e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb) and I see that flash messages apparently get saved not only to the session, but also to `@env`. So I performed the following experiment.

```
# I'm manually setting a flash message
> flash[:notice] = "hello"

# Now I'm checking for the flash message in env
> env["action_dispatch.request.flash_hash"]

=> #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fda544718b0
@discard=#<Set: {}>,
@flashes={:notice=>"hello"},
@now=nil>

# Now I'm checking for it in the session
> session["flash"]
=> nil
```

And then if I do a Pry on the controller action to which my redirect goes, I can do this:

```
> env["action_dispatch.request.flash_hash"]
```

And it returns `nil`.

### Env sometimes, session never

My `HashFlash` evidently makes it into `env` sometimes, `session` *never*. The fact that it never gets into `session` strikes me as probably incorrect behavior.

### My redirect code

```
def update
  user_params.delete(:password) if user_params && user_params[:password].blank?
  if user.update_attributes(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to(user_account_path(user, anchor: params[:tab]), notice: "Your account has been updated")
      end
      format.js
    end
  else
    render :show
  end
end
```

I know for a fact that control is getting to the redirect. I've also tried changing the code to this with no luck.

```
def update
  # Redirect right away to kill the extra moving parts
  redirect_to(user_account_path(user, anchor: params[:tab]), notice: "Your account has been updated")
  return

  user_params.delete(:password) if user_params && user_params[:password].blank?
  if user.update_attributes(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to(user_account_path(user, anchor: params[:tab]), notice: "Your account has been updated")
      end
      format.js
    end
  else
    render :show
  end
end
```

So my question is: **how can I get my flash messages to work again?**

**Edit**: When I manually set `session["flash"]` to `flash.to_session_value`, the flash message comes across, although then it's permanently "stuck on". That seems like a clue, though.

**Edit 2**: I've learned, by doing some inspection on a known-working project, that `session["flash"]` can never be expected to be present immediately after assigning a value to `flash[:notice]` (or whatever other key). Apparently the flash messages are only plugged into `session` after the controller action returns. So that solves that part of the mystery.

**Edit 3**: FWIW, here's the output of `rake middleware`:

```
use Airbrake::UserInformer
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007fcc23268eb8>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use BetterErrors::Middleware
use Airbrake::Rails::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Warden::Manager
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use OmniAuth::Builder
run DueProps::Application.routes
```

I don't know if that provides any clues or not.

Comment: why don't you directly use `flash`?

Comment: You mean why don't I put `flash[:notice] = "Your account has been updated"` in the controller? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Try this `flash["notice"] = "Your account has been updated"`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried checking for the `flash` object after the redirect instead of looking in `session['flash']`?

Comment: Yes. At that point in time `flash` is an empty `FlashHash` object.

Comment: Are you redirecting in `user_account_path` as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426526/flash-message-in-redirect-not-working

Comment: No, `user_account_path` is just a plain `show` action with just a single variable assignment.

Comment: And I tried [this answer from your linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9299107/199712), which I imagine would solve any issue involving multiple redirects, but it had no effect. I'm also only seeing one redirect in the logs. So it doesn't seem like the issue is multiple redirects.

Comment: Have you run `rake middleware` to verify that `use ActionDispatch::Flash` is actually in your middleware stack?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran `rake middleware` and `use ActionDispatch::Flash` does in fact show up in the output. I'm not familiar with what `rake middleware` is all about so I'll go look that up. Maybe that will lead me to more clues.

Comment: BTW, I edited my question to include the output of `rake middleware` in case that contains any clues.

Comment: Okay, I finally solved the problem. Thanks, everyone, especially @jbgo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit. Someone had added this in `config/application.rb`:

```
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
```

Thus, `rake middleware` was showing two each of `ActionDispatch::Cookies` and `ActionDispatch::Session`:

```
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore

use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

Once we removed those two lines, flash messages worked once again.

I have to thank @jbgo because his comment is what led me to the solution.

Comment: I just spent an hour debugging flash messages. The culprit was using lvh.me as a domain name with multiple subdomains for development. Switched back to localhost and the flash messages reappeared.

Comment: This is a genius post. Thank you! Not sure I would have gotten it without this. My flash messages weren't persisting in devise after I manually set `inactive_message` for `active_for_authentication?` and this was the culprit.