# How do I diagnose disappearing flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

I have created a record as usual and byebug has confirmed that flash message is created. But when I get redirected I see no flashes at all. Does flash get deleted in some circumstances? How can I fix it? I use a custom built omniauth authorization method. If that is causing a problem how do I investigate it further?

```
[262, 271] in /home/jacekp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@rails4qc_charts/gems/actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb
   262:       session    = Request::Session.find(env) || {}
   263:       flash_hash = env[KEY]
   264: 
   265:       if flash_hash && (flash_hash.present? || session.key?('flash'))
   266:         session["flash"] = flash_hash.to_session_value
=> 267:         env[KEY] = flash_hash.dup
   268:       end
   269: 
   270:       if (!session.respond_to?(:loaded?) || session.loaded?) && # (reset_session uses {}, which doesn't implement #loaded?)
   271:         session.key?('flash') && session['flash'].nil?
(byebug)  session["flash"] 
{"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Sample was successfully created."}}
(byebug) n

[266, 275] in /home/jacekp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@rails4qc_charts/gems/actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb
   266:         session["flash"] = flash_hash.to_session_value
   267:         env[KEY] = flash_hash.dup
   268:       end
   269: 
   270:       if (!session.respond_to?(:loaded?) || session.loaded?) && # (reset_session uses {}, which doesn't implement #loaded?)
=> 271:         session.key?('flash') && session['flash'].nil?
   272:         session.delete('flash')
   273:       end
   274:     end
   275:   end
```

## experiment

I have inserted byebug in .rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@rails4qc_charts/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/request.rb in

```
  def session; byebug ;        @env['rack.session'] ||= {}              end
```

to see what is happening and tried a page that sets flash in session. 
I was examing it with

> (byebug)  @env['rack.session'].keys

and did not find anything that would give me a clue.

Comment: Is the session being reseted after setting the flash?

Comment: @CAmador I do not know how to find the answer to your question :-( grepping the project code did not show anything.

Comment: Save something in the session (`session[:foo] = 'bar'`) right before the flash, then add `<% byebug %>` on top of the template  and check the session content.

Comment: @CAmador I can save session['foo'] and it works. but why flashes get deleted? is it possible that my authentication solution is doing some redirects behind the scenes and the flash is deleted because of that?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, too. Check the log to confirm.

Comment: @CAmador sadly there is nothing in the logs. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/omniauth/OmniAuth%2FStrategy:redirect says there can be some redirection involded

Comment: You can watch the Network tab on your browser's dev tools as a last resource. I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @CAmador firefox network tab did not show anything about authentication redirection.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I had a better idea what to google for and found this post:
[Rails flash missing from session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122340/rails-flash-missing-from-session)

so I have commented out the error in my 
config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies # Required for all session management
#config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, config.session_options
```

Before commenting out the second line I had the disappearing flash error.